# cloudkit saverecord method makes app crash

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

fyi, i'm following this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_8_CloudKit_Example#Saving_a_Record_to_the_Cloud_Database)

The following method crashes my app in the simulator and a device (5S). The crashes happens at the "`publicDatabase!`" line.

I get the following generic error

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
@IBAction func saveRecord(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (photoURL == nil) {
        notifyUser("No Photo", message: "Use the Photo option to choose a photo for the record")
        return
    }

    let asset = CKAsset(fileURL: photoURL!)

    let myRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Houses")
    myRecord.setObject(addressField.text, forKey: "address")
    myRecord.setObject(commentsField.text, forKey: "comment")
    myRecord.setObject(asset, forKey: "photo")

    publicDatabase!.saveRecord(myRecord, completionHandler:
        ({returnRecord, error in
            if let err = error {
                self.notifyUser("Save Error", message:
                    err.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.notifyUser("Success",
                        message: "Record saved successfully")
                }
                self.currentRecord = myRecord
            }
        }))
}
```

Can anyone provide assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `publicDatabase` it'll be `nil` because probably you didn't initialized it.

In the code provided there is no relevant code with `publicDatabase` initialization. So verify that you initialized it before using.